# Is there a shorthand for this get response returning a HTTP error?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I really have no idea what to search for to get the answer to this:

Is there a short hand for this block:

```
get '/' do
  501
end
```

I got started by following the rubymonk.com tutorial and it implied there was generally common-sense shorthand to most things in ruby but I tried the following with no luck:

```
get '/' 501
get '/' (501)
get '/' {501}
get '/' do 501
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get('/') { 501 }
```

Seems to be an issue with Ruby syntax.

`get '/' { 501 }` (`f g x`) seems to be interpreted as `get('/'({ 501 }))` (`f(g(x))`) which is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what version of Ruby you are using, maybe 1.8.7, on Ruby 1.9 and 2.1.0 the error reported for the code `get '/' { 501 }` is:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
```

The cause is that the parser tries to tie the block `{ 501 }` to the literal `'/'`, i.e. the code is parsed like `get('\' { 501 })`, that is obviously an error. You just have to disambiguate the syntax by putting parentheses around the `'\'` argument:

```
get('/') { 501 }
```